# How to generate the F# type signature similar to FSI in my own code?

Tags: f#, type-inference, linqpad, f#-interactive

If one uses the F# Interactive Shell (FSI), the inferred expression type ([signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx)) is printed to the console along with its value:

```
val it : int * string * float = (42, "Hello F#", 42.0)
```

How can I mimick the same behaviour in my own code, e.g. to get the inferred types as string for a F# expression?

I don't need to dynamically evaluate any F# expressions, the expressions are known in compile time and are part of my (static) F# code. I need this feature to be able to mimick the FSI output in LINQPad for my F# demos.

Comment: If the expressions are known ahead-of-time, why not run them through FSI ahead-of-time as well?

Comment: @pblasucci I use LinqPAD for live coding and it works perfectly well with F#. Switching to FSI every time I need to show a signature for an expression would be too much time waste. But I keep it as an option, thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin Can LinqPAD execute a shell command?  You could shell out and run the fsc command with the --sig flag and pass it the file you're currently working on.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Yes, that would be a solution too. But for demo purposes it is much easier just to type the signature manually -- I just wanted to show how to read these signatures to F# beginners and looked for a quick solution which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I don't think I understand the scenario, so maybe this isn't relevant, but anyway: If you activate the premium features of LINQPad, mousing over source will show the type info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Using Unquote

[Unquote](https://github.com/SwensenSoftware/unquote) has a facility for getting the F# signature of a type. Simply download the latest release and add a reference through LINQPad to Unquote.dll, then you can do e.g.

[image]

If you're interested, you can peak at the source code for the implementation of the `FSharpName` `Type` extension: https://github.com/SwensenSoftware/unquote/blob/2.1.0/Unquote/ExtraReflection.fs#L54

## Using FsEye

Another neat approach would be to use LINQPad's beta [Custom Visualizer](http://www.linqpad.net/CustomVisualizers.aspx) API to embed [FsEye](https://github.com/swensensoftware/fseye) into LINQPad (FsEye uses the same F# type signature printing algorithm as Unquote). This is also very simple, all you need to do is download [LINQPad beta](http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx), download and reference FsEye.dll from the latest release of FsEye, then you can do e.g.

[image]

Comment: I **love** those environment mixing data and metadata. I would equally love them right within visual studio, doing expression replacement to have concrete results of functions we are writing...

Comment: Rather than download and ref a dll manually, since LinqPad beta supports nuget packages, maybe a nuget package of the FsEye dll?

Comment: Good suggestion @jbtule. I've had in mind to create an FsEye NuGet package for some time. Scenarios like this are good motivation. I actually already have an issue written for this (different motivation, but same ends): https://code.google.com/p/fseye/issues/detail?id=30

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, the unquote solution seems no longer to work (at least for me). I tried the following code snippet:

type Test()=member public this.s2()="Hello"

let x=new Test()

x.GetType().FSharpName

returns a string and Dump does not exist.

Comment: @AndreasMorgenstern I've got to imagine you are experiencing a user error: `Dump()` is an extension method LinqPAD provides for all `Object` types. If it "doesn't exist", that is problem above Unquote. Perhaps post a question with precise repo steps to get better help.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the F# compiler code and see how the --sig option is handled by the compiler I think that will get you what you're looking for.  More about the --sig option and signatures here:

[Signatures (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion -- I added the signatures to my question. Trying to delve into the compiler implementation seems like an overkill for me, sorry.

Comment: Why not just use the `--sig` option and present the signature file during the demos?

Comment: I thought he was asking how to do this programmatically.

Comment: @RamonSnir THe idea is not to show how to generate signatures. Rather, I just want to show some typical functions and explain what they expect and what they return -- running compiler every time to produce a signature is too much work here, it will be easier for me just to write the signature by heart.