# F# type inference (compiler output)

Tags: ide, f#, type-inference

Is there a way to get a structured output of the result of type inference by the F# compiler?

(I am trying to build a small IDE).

Comment: I think the accepted answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908052/how-to-generate-the-f-type-signature-similar-to-fsi-in-my-own-code is what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have a file `test.fs`, you can use the following command to generate F# Signature File `test.fsi`, which contains type information about all top-level definitions:

```
Fsc.exe --sig:test.fsi test.fs
```

To get information about local variables, you'll need to use the F# compiler as a service. There is a simple [command-line example](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=fsharp%20intellisense%20tool&referringTitle=Home) that demonstrates how to call the API and you can also explore the [F# binding for MonoDevelop](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding).