# How to print from F# like REPL does

Tags: f#

I am trying to use F# as a REPL and scripting which uses C# library. When I evaluate an object in REPL, it prints its internal structure:

```
> <expression>;;
val it: <type> =
 <subtype> {<prop> = <value>;
            ...
            <prop> = <value>;}
```

Then I am writing a script with the same expression and want it to print same output. But I cannot find any `print` function which would do it. The closest I could find is `printfn "%O"` which uses ToString() method, which is not defined in my case and just prints the object type.

This seems to be a simple question but I cannot find it answered here or anywhere in Google.

[How to generate the F# type signature similar to FSI in my own code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9908052/2303202) seems to be focused on type, and I basically need rather pretty-printed value.

PS: seems like it is code which is internal to fsi.exe. See [fsi.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/2dae2cdea47a7faec164e81e5ed722125d126334/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs) and [sformat.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/835b79c041f9032fceeceb39f680e0662cba92ec/src/utils/sformat.fsi) sources. I tried to invoke them through reflection, but simple `Internal.Utilities.StructuredFormat.any_to_string(value)` printed just a type. Would still be nice if anybody knows how to invoke it correctly, but for time being I decided not to spend more efforts on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate the F# type signature similar to FSI in my own code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908052/how-to-generate-the-f-type-signature-similar-to-fsi-in-my-own-code)

Comment: what about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791706/how-do-i-customize-output-of-a-custom-type-using-printf?

Comment: @helge-rene-urholm that seems to involve changing the object type itself; I cannot do it because it's from library. Actually, I wonder how they achieved "both print statements yield: {a = 5;}" result there; this is exactly what I'd need

Comment: Have you tried `printfn "%A"`? It sounds like that's what you're actually looking for, not `%O`.

Comment: @rmunn yes I did, both just prints the object's class name

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, but in my case, `printfn "%A"` gave exactly the same result as what I see in F# Interactive (bar the indentation):

For a list:

```
> let l = [(2,"a")];;
val l : (int * string) list = [(2, "a")]
> printfn "%A" l;;
[(2, "a")]
```

For a record:

```
> type R = { A: string; B: int };;
type R =
  {A: string;
   B: int;}
> let r = { A = "Foo"; B = 1 };;
val r : R = {A = "Foo";
             B = 1;}
> printfn "%A" r;;
{A = "Foo";
 B = 1;}
```

For a non-F# datatype:

```
> let u = UriBuilder("http", "bar", 80);;
val u : UriBuilder = http://bar:80/
> printfn "%A" u;;
http://bar:80/
```

Comment: it looks like properly defined .ToString method. In my case there was none. The output from REPL prints object internals then.

Comment: I think then I still don't get your issue. What are the datatypes for which you get a different output in REPL, when compared to what you get when using `printfn "%A"` ? Some C# class?

Comment: Yes, C# class. From some library which is not mine. I'll try to provide example as I have time, but as far as I remember it was very straightforward.